# What is the value of $<u,v>^2$?

Tags: inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space. What is the value of $<u,v>^2 = <u,v> <u,v> $?

where $u, v \in V$ and $<,>$ is the inner product on $V$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking what the definition of $\langle u,v\rangle$ is?

Comment: $\langle u,v \rangle ^2 = \langle u,v \rangle \, \langle u,v \rangle\,$. Did you mean to ask something else maybe?

Comment: It depends on what $u$ and $v$ are. Generically, $<u,v>^2=(u_1v_1+\dots+u_nv_n)^2$, and you can develop the square of the sum.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$ then

$<u,v>^2=||u||^2*||v||^2*\cos^2(\alpha)$

Comment: Ooops, of course, angle !